# How can I make an append of a very large panda dataframe, without having to take the data to the ram?

Tags: python, dataframe, memory, bigdata, in-place

I have a very large dataframe in a pickle file, and I would like to append another dataframe (with the same number and type of columns) to that file (without having to load the file into ram). How can I do this?